Xharness with xunit break on unit tests that use Android Assets
Good afternoon,
I have a MAUI unit test app (Android) based on xUnit.
This app has "two entry points": test instrumentation (headless) and visual entry point (app). This is loosely based on this MAUI source code example.
All tests run (and pass) fine when launched from Visual Studio (ie visual entry point).
All tests run (and pass) fine if headless entry point is called when launched from VisualStudio.
The instrumentation is used with xharness. The objective is to use this under CI job so it can run the unit tests of the project.
The tests that make use of Android Assets all fail as soon as you try to open an asset using the AssetManager when launched using xharness. The exception is the null exception:
Object reference not set to an instance of an object

I also use some TestFixtures (IClassFixture) in order to achieve similar nUnit functionality Setup etc as explained in here. If the access to asset is done here then the exception is slightly different but the stackt of the exception ends up showing the same as above:
Exception messages: System.AggregateException : AggregateException_ctor_DefaultMessage (Object reference not set to an instance of an object) (The following constructor parameters did not have matching fixture data: XXXX fixture)
System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object
The following constructor parameters did not have matching fixture data: TestColourClassificationFixture fixture   Exception stack traces: 
----- Inner Stack Trace #1 (System.NullReferenceException) -----

The project is built and ran through xharness with:
dotnet build Android.Test.csproj -c Release -f net7.0-android
xharness android test --output-directory=test_results  --package-name=com.example.android.test --app=Android.Test/bin/Release/net7.0-android/com.example.android.test-Signed.apk --instrumentation=com.example.android.test.TestInstrumentation

I've checked:

The apk contains the assets - it does.
The Asset Manager is not null for some reason - it is not.
Tried disabling the parallel nature of xunit tests when they run and run them in sequence one by one. This is based on some posts i read about parallelisation causing race conditions - this does not change anything and the tests accessing assets still fail.

What am I possible missing here? Why does Visual Studio launches and runs the tests ok but xharness doesn't? It's definitely related with access to file (assets) but i'm not sure what...

If anyone comes across this for some reason, i was using AssetsManager and this for some reason does not work in my case.
Using
Platform.AppContext.Assets

worked ok.
Not sure if it's related with being MAUI template app even though i only target .net-android.
